# I can't access public folder from css file of my app

Tags: css, reactjs, background-image, filepath

I'm trying to access the logo image which is in public folder while my css folder is in src. I'm also using sass and I took into consideration that we need to write the path relatively to css file - not sass.

I tried different ways - with absolute path, with quotes and without - just hoped that maybe something will work.

I found someone's code `https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-rosalind-21lsd?file=/src/App.js` and played with it - I created same conditions as I have and it worked, but when I go back to my project it doesn't.

I'm using background-image: url('/logo.swg'), and it says `Error: Can't resolve '/logo.swg'`.

I'm aware of ejecting and webpack configuration changes, also I know that if I change the css and sass folders' path moving it outside of src it may theoretically work (with an absolute path I guess - since React does not allow us to refer to files outside of src directory).

I'm wondering if something changed in React, does anyone know? It works when I write the url as inline style, and it works when I import it in js files.

Thanks in advance.

`versions`:

react^17.0.1
react-scripts^4.0.1
create-react-app^4.0.2

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo. But the filename should be `logo.svg` and not `logo.swg`.

Comment: omg my fault  I amended but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io)? Without a minimal reproducible example, it's hard to help I am afraid.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-lovelace-wimww?file=/src/App.js         well I just created and it's almost the same structure as mine. css file imported to index.js, css directory where styles.css is, the logo in public folder. But in my project it doesn't work and I don't know why  i tried to kill the process and started again - it also didnt help

Comment: That is super weird. There must be something missing. Can you check if there are any differences in terms of how the app is set up?

Comment: do u mean versions ? i checked the package.json in codesandbox, react version is the same as mine. and i just checked the css compiled file - it is as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following list as quick reference:

```
    /   = Root directory
   .   = This location
   ..  = Up a directory
   ./  = Current directory
   ../ = Parent of current directory
   ../../ = Two directories backwards
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference :) however, I know the meaning of those symbols - some people say that the problem is in CRA 4, and just discovered that an issue is opened at Github https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10022